# IOS: reload a tableview with custom tableview cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uitableview

In my project I have a tableview with 20 custom tableviewcell; when I call the view where is my tableview the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

fill my table with custom tableviewcells...and it's all ok.

In my custom tableviewcells I have a UIImageView that I fill with a .png, and all works fine. 
But if I want change this UIImageView with another .png? I must reload another time my tableview with all tableviewcells...no? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must reload the visible cells whose views you want to change. `[tableView visibleCells]`. The rest will change automatically while you scroll the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your imageview is part of the view hierarchy like any other view. The important thing is to keep a reference to the imageview in question so you're still able to easily access it.

You might want to do this by connecting the view to an outlet of your tableviewcontroller (if you have set your custom cells up in interface builder) or by assigning the view to an ivar of your tableviewcontroller right after you created the cell programmatically.

If you'd like to do this with with all of your cells, it might be a good idea to add all of the imageviews you'd like to be able to edit to an array. If the cells won't be reordered then adding them one after the other should be ok, you could retrieve them using the index from the table view cell in question. If the table may be reordered by the user you need to identify the views using tags (or similar means).